# Android4.4 source code compile

Tags: android, ubuntu

when  i  want  to   compile  Android4.4   on  Ubtunu 13.10 ,it  gives  an  error  as   follow,
[image: the problem]

Comment: You aren't linking to the pthread library.

Comment: how   to  solve   thi  problem ?